# Group theory: Prove that if the inverse element of $a$ is $a^{-1}$, then the inverse element of $a^{-1}$ is $a$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Prove that if the inverse element of $a$ is $a^{-1}$, then the inverse element of $a^{-1}$ is $a$, meaning $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$ where $a^{-1} \in G$, where $G$ is a group.

This is how I did it but I'm not sure if it is the correct approach:

Let $e$ be the identity element of group $G$. Since the inverse element of $a$ is $a^{-1}$, then the following holds:

$aa^{-1}=e=a^{-1}a \implies a^{-1}a=e$. Therefore the inverse of $a^{-1}$ is $a$.

Comment: Another way: $(a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1} = e$, then $(a^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1}a = ea = a$, then $(a^{-1})^{-1}e = a$, then $(a^{1})^{-1} = a$

Comment: **Learn to ask Google** before asking here. I have typed "group inverse of inverse" and found many answers in some seconds !

Comment: I did try googling it but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer. It's probably because I searched "if the inverse of a is b then the inverse of b is a" instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When you think to a query : place the words in decreasing order of importance (you see : I have placed "group" first, I could have also "placed "mathematics" before "group" in order to avoid answers with, for example "group of people", and then very few "connecting words". For example in the query you give as an example, "if the" is superfluous, the same for "then the"...

Comment: $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a\iff a^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}=e$, which is true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that seems like a good solution. Quick note, $e$ is generally called the identity element. But your solution looks good. It may be helpful to fully write out the reasoning involved. From $aa^{-1}=e=a^{-1}a$, you have derived $a^{-1}a=e=a^{-1}$. It would be helpful to note this asserts that $a$ satisfies the defining property of $(a^{-1})^{-1}$. Since inverses are unique
$(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$. But, if I were grading, I would accept your solution.